# How does sending an argument that's casted to a pointer to a function that accepts pointer work? Shouldn't I send the ADDRESS of the argument?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, type-conversion

I understand the way `print1` function works, but how come when calling `print2` function I don't need to pass the **address** of the argument but rather I just need to cast it to void pointer? I don't understand how the output is correct. What does it mean when I say `(void*)20`? And then what does the whole "`int n = (int)param` inside the `print2` function does?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print1(void* param)
{
    int n = *((int*)param);
    printf("You sent: %d\n", n);
}

void print2(void* param)
{
    int n = (int)param;
    printf("You sent: %d\n", n);
}

int main()
{
    int number = 10;
    print1(&number);

    print2((void*)20);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's implementation-defined.

Comment: That's because `print2` has bad code. it is casting a pointer to an int which shold not be done. That is, `print2` is not actually treating the input param as a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(void *)20` converts `20` to a pointer. Per C 2018 6.3.2.3 5, the result is implementation-defined.

`print2((void*)20);` sends that pointer to `print2`.

In `print2`, `int n = (int)param;` converts that pointer back to `int`. Per C 2018 6.3.2.3 6, the result is implementation-defined. A common result is that the original integer is restored, provided it has not run afoul of limitations or complications in the addressing mechanism used in the C implementation.

`printf("You sent: %d\n", n);` sends this restored `int` to `printf`.